# touchstart firing twice on iphone

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, touchstart

I'm using this to hide/show a menu on small screen touch devices:

```
    $('.menuButton').bind('touchstart',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('nav.mainNav ul li').toggle();
});
```

It appears to be firing twice on iphone, quickly displaying and disappearing again. This only the first time, works perfectly after that.

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It might be you have some code getting triggered too, somewhere out of sight. Other problem could be that you have css-ed the `nav.mainNav ul li` with `!important`, than the animation works and hops back to the value of the important